# Realizar reporte entre varias tablas con Eloquent Laravel

Tags: sql, eloquent

Tengo una relación de muchos a muchos entre Usuarios y Tareas

> Usuarios(id,nombre..)
>
> usuario_tarea(id_user, id_tarea)
>
> Tareas (id, tarea, estado) (ESTADO= finalizado, proceso, demorado)

Necesito traer por usuario la cantidad de tareas totales y cuantas estan en finalizado, en proceso, demorado, el cual no me está saliendo.

Por ejemplo

Juan Lopez
 Tareas totales 35
 En proceso: 7 
 Demoradas: 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algo así podría guiarte un poco:

Traes los usuarios eager loadeando las tareas en el controlador y se lo pasas a la vista:

```
$usuarios = Usuario::with("tareas")->get();
return view('unavista', compact("usuarios"));
```

Luego en la vista:

```
@foreach($usuarios as $usuario){
    nombre:{{$usuario->nombre}}<br>
    Tareas totales: {{$usuario->tareas->count()}}<br> 
    En proceso: {{$usuario->tareas->where('estado', 'proceso')->count()}}<br> 
    Demoradas: {{$usuario->tareas->where('estado', 'demorado')->count()}}<br>
}
```

**UPDATE 2° Consulta:**

Esto debería funcionar (en el controller):

```
$usuarios= Usuario::with("tareas")
->withCount('tareas')
->orderBy('tareas_count', 'desc')
->get();
```

Comment: Era mucho mas facil de lo que quería inventar, gracias!

Comment: Como puedo ordenar de mayor a menor dependiend la cantidad de tareas ?